# How covert upload functionality to S3 bucket in AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload

Currently we are connecting with one file share path for uploading files.Now I need to changes this file share path to s3 bucket.I need to connect with S3 bucket for uploading file.
Here is the sample code is

```
import java.util.Vector;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;


public class JSCH_FTP_Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, SftpException {

        Session session = null;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
         Channel     channel = null;
        String remoteDirectory = "/test";
        String getFtpHost="http://localhost:";
        String getFtpUser="test";
        String getFtpPasswd="test";
        session = jsch.getSession(getFtpUser,getFtpHost);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(getFtpPasswd);
        session.setConfig("cipher.s2c", "aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        channelSftp.cd(remoteDirectory);
        Vector filelist = channelSftp.ls(remoteDirectory);
        for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
            LsEntry entry = (LsEntry) filelist.get(i);
            System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
        }

    }

}
```

I am using jcsh.jar for uploading the files.

Answer (score 1):

AWS sdk are available for JAVA or Scala to interact with s3.
Refer to below links for more details:
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

For python you can use boto3 library for the same.